# Trying to use column which is created with FORMAT function to be a date in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table and one of the column was created with FORMAT function. I had a datetime column, but I wanted only the date, so what I did:

```
FORMAT(hug2.Slots.DateStart, 'd', 'en-gb') AS 'DateStart'
```

I can see that the column type is nvarchar(4000).
I am trying to use this column in a WHERE clause, what I am after is:

```
WHERE DateStart >= 01/09/2023
```

but my result includes records where DateStart is less that the specified 01/09/2023 date.

I have tried writing:

```
WHERE DateStart >= '01/09/2023'

WHERE DateStart >= 2023-09-01

WHERE DateStart >= 01-09-2023

WHERE DateStart > FORMAT(01/09/2023, 'd', 'en-gb')
```

The whole block of code is:

```
SELECT r.Reference, r.flag_batch_ready,
    CASE 
        WHEN p.Tenure IS NULL THEN r.Tenure
        ELSE p.Tenure
    END AS 'Property_Tenure',
    mxspr.Status AS 'Max_Survey_Status',
    CASE
        WHEN r.GSEHousePlanUploaded IS NULL THEN 'No'
        WHEN r.GSEHousePlanUploaded = 0  THEN 'No'
        WHEN  r.GSEHousePlanUploaded = 1 THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'to check'
    END AS 'HP_uploaded',
    mxspr.DateStart

FROM hug2.ReferralUpdates r

    LEFT JOIN hug2.max_survey_status_per_ref mxspr
        ON r.Reference = mxspr.Reference

    LEFT JOIN hug2.max_propertyId_per_ref p
        ON r.Reference = p.Reference

WHERE mxspr.DateStart > '01/09/2023'
```

nothing returns the result that I want.

Comment: Use an *unambigous* date format. I suggest `yyyyMMdd` for a `date`. Also, as a side note, `01-09-2023` is an expression of `int`s; it would result in the value `-2031`. Date literals need to go in single quotes (`'`).

Comment: If the original column was date time, then you could just cast it in the where clause with something like `WHERE CAST(myOriginalColum as Date) > CAST('20230901' as Date)`

Comment: Why would you expect arithmetic to be sensitive to your intent? `01/09/2023` and `2023-09-01` seem easy enough to compute, but the result is probably not what you would want to compare to a date. Also note that comparing strings in _alphabetical_ order when they contain dates that don't sort gracefully is likely to be unhelpful, e.g. `'10/10/2010'` is greater than `'01/01/2020'`. If you only want a date then use a [`date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), perhaps as a _computed column_.

Comment: The OP would be better off writing `myOriginalColumn >= '20230902'` for that, @AlanSchofield .

Comment: @ThomA, that's true, I guess I was thinking about if it was `=` rather then `>=` and the original column included a valid time (excluding 00:00:00)